# Visual studio code integrated terminal path different than normal terminal

Tags: macos, path, visual-studio-code, .bash-profile, macos-mojave

I am on MacOS Mojave and I can't figure out why visual studio code's integrated terminal has a different path variable than the normal terminal.

I have checked that VSCode opens `/bin/bash` (`echo $SHELL` yields `/bin/bash`).

However when executing `echo $PATH` in the integrated terminal it yields `/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/anaconda3/bin:/anaconda3/condabin` while on the normal terminal it gives `/anaconda3/bin:/anaconda3/condabin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`

They both source `~/.bash_profile` which contains the following :

```
# added by Anaconda3 2018.12 installer
# >>> conda init >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
__conda_setup="$(CONDA_REPORT_ERRORS=false '/anaconda3/bin/conda' shell.bash hook 2> /dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    \eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        . "/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
        CONDA_CHANGEPS1=false conda activate base
    else
        \export PATH="/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
    fi
fi
unset __conda_setup
```

Even after sourcing `~/.bash_profile` in the integrated terminal, /anaconda3/bin is at the end while `~/.bash_profile` prepends it which is confusing.

I think the default path must be added after bash_profile is sourced in the integrated terminal? Not sure how it works

I am hesitating to post this as an issue in the vscode repo but I just wanted to make sure it isn't my understanding that is off.

Answer (score 11):

In Visual Studio Code open Settings (JSON) from the command palete (⇧⌘P), and at the end of the file add the following

```
"terminal.integrated.env.osx": {
        "PATH": ""
}
```

Restart VSCode and you are all set.

Taken from https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python/issues/4434

Comment: I had exactly same problem with it and the workaround still DOES work!

Comment: This worked for me on Windows 10 with PowerShell 7. This is super weird and annoying. `$ENV:PATH` did NOT match between VSCode Terminal and Windows Terminal when using the same exact PowerShell instance until I applied this to `terminal.integrated.profiles.windows`. So confusing.

Comment: The issue was with me for the whole afternoon util I tried this trick.

Answer (score 5):

You can uncheck `Terminal › Integrated: Inherit Env` option, which can be searched by `terminal.integrated.inheritEnv`, in Visual Studio Code Settings like the following image:

[image]

Referece: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/70248#issuecomment-502186149 (Now the option `terminal.integrated.inheritEnv` is included in the stable build.)

Answer (score 2):

Turning off the `Enable Persistent Sessions` settings fixed it for me.

[image: Enable Persistent Sessions Settings Screenshot]

It seems that, when this setting is on, VSCode caches the value of `PATH` and never updates it.

Source for the solution is [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71503669/10601702).